# Assigning JSON object to an extended TypeScript class

Tags: json, angular, typescript, class

Requirement came in to add an extra property.

I extended an existing class by adding a new property, but when I assign JSON object from database the new
property disappears. Is there a way to properly assign json obj into a ts class so the ts class instance doesn't lose the property and cause data binding error?
Trying to avoid any extra code to check the JSON...

Appreciate any help

e.g.

```
let JSONObject = {
 FirstName: "Json",
 LastName: "Born"
};

class Person {
 FirstName: string = "Jason";
 MiddleName: string = "Unknown";
 LastName: string = "Bourne";
}

let PersonA = new Person();

console.log(PersonA); **//{FirstName:"Jason", MiddleName: "Unknown", LastName: "Bourne"}**

PersonA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
//also tried **PersonA = <Person>JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSONObject));**


console.log(PersonA); **//{FirstName:"Json", LastName: "Born"}**
```

Tried searching by JSON object to TypeScript class,

Comment: line `PersonA = JSON.parse ...` overwrites what you set in `let PersonA = new Person()`
this can work: `PersonA = { ...PersonA, ...JSONObject };`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to explicitly map your `JSONObject` property values to the properties of an object of type `Person`. The reason is because the JSON isn't really an object of a given type (it could be mapped to anything).

So what you might consider doing is something like this:

```
let JSONObject = {
 FirstName: "Json",
 LastName: "Born"
};

class Person {
 FirstName: string = "Jason";
 MiddleName: string = "Unknown";
 LastName: string = "Bourne";
}

let PersonA = new Person();
PersonA.FirstName = JSONObject.FirstName;
PersonA.LastName = JSONObject.LastName;
PersonA.MiddleName = "...";
```

Or...

```
let PersonA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(JSONObject));
PersonA.MiddleName = "...";
```

Not entirely sure where you're getting that `MiddleName` value from though; if your web service is returning it in the `JSONObject` assignment, then it'll be there anyway and you could do a direct parse to the class... otherwise you'll have to map it because the parse simply doesn't know what to do with the MiddleName property that doesn't have a value in the source JSON.

HTH

Comment: I could do the mapping of course but in my case the new property is deeply buried inside on of the nested sub classes. 

MiddleName is a user input, will not generate (if not already inputted) at first but show as an empty text box